# Hadoop Docker Setup - WordCount Tutorial

Tags: java, hadoop, docker

I was following the tutorial to run `WordCount.java` mentioned in [here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/other/tutorial/CDH5/topics/ht_usage.html) and when I run the following line in the tutorial

```
hadoop jar wordcount.jar org.myorg.WordCount /user/cloudera/wordcount/input /user/cloudera/wordcount/output
```

I get the following error -

```
17/09/04 01:57:29 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
17/09/04 01:57:30 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

The docker image that I used was `docker pull cloudera/quickstart`

There were no setup tutorials for Hadoop with Docker so it would be helpful if you could tell me the configurations that are to be made to overcome these issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That tutorial assumes you are in the cluster with the Hadoop client command available, the Hadoop Services are started, and properly configured.

`0.0.0.0:8032` is [the default YARN resource manager](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml), so you need to configure your `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` XML files (specifically `yarn-site` for this error) to point at the Docker container for the correct addresses of YARN. `core` and `hdfs-site` will need configured to point at HDFS as well.

Comment: Is there a way to find out which IP and port is to be used? And where do I configure these settings - because there are multiple yarn-site.xml files?

Comment: There should only be one yarn-site file. And unless you have properly exposed the ports for YARN,HDFS,etc from the container the IP or hostname is the docker container. Otherwise, it's your localhost

Comment: I assume your answer is correct. I was able to solve it docker run --hostname=quickstart.cloudera --privileged=true -t -i -p 8888 cloudera/quickstart /usr/bin/docker-quickstart. The -p option is mentioned as Recommended but not required but from this experience I believe that is required atleast if anyone wants to follow through with this tutorial. https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/other/tutorial/CDH5/topics/ht_usage.html. Please add this extra detail so that I can accept your answer.

Comment: Add what extra detail? It should be sufficient to say all you did was open up the container ports and mapped its hostname so your host machine can resolve it by DNS name. For example, `--net=host --hostname=quickstart.cloudera --privileged=true` is another solution without `-p`